# Calculating Feature Importance of Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, feature-extraction

I am new to time-series modeling, and I was wondering what the standard way of quantifying feature importances are in a time-series setting? What types of models allow for the greatest interpretation of the feature space?

I am looking for something, which does not necessarily function like the Random Forest Regressor's feature importance call, but provides a similar insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For time series data,

1. Sensitivity analysis can help with overall Importance of a feature. For example, is  "Day of the week" a good feature for stock price forecasting. LIME is one approach that can help. Details :  https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05386 . One simple way is to mask each feature and check the impact on model's performance.
2. Auto-corelation and Seasonality removal  (Details in tutorial at end of the answer)
3. SHAP : (SHapley Additive exPlanations) is good at identifying features that impact output with lag (https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/time-step-wise-feature-importance-in-deep-learning-using-shap-e1c46a655455)

End to end example : 
https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-time-series-forecasting-python/